# Create Payment Schedule Dates Based on Term and Interval

Tags: sas

I'm trying to find the best way to create a loop to advance a date.  Here's an example of what my data looks like:

```
data example;
   format first_pmt_date mmddyys10.0;
   format schedule $25.;

   id=1;
   first_pmt_date="28JAN2011"d;
   schedule='Bi-Weekly';
   term=52;
   output;

   id=2;
   first_pmt_date="15JAN2011"d;
   schedule='Weekly';
   term=156;
   output;

   id=3;
   first_pmt_date="23JAN2011"d;
   schedule='Semi-Monthly';
   term=72;
   output;
run;
```

I'd like to create a loop to advance the first_pmt_date based on the payment scheudule (bi-weekly, semi-monthly, weekly).  For example, in the case of id 2 above, I'd have 156 rows with all of the payment dates advancing weekly from 1/15/2011. Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
id  first_pmt_date  schedule    term    scheduled_pmt_date
2   01/15/2011      Weekly      156     1/15/2011
2   01/15/2011      Weekly      156     1/22/2011
2   01/15/2011      Weekly      156     1/29/2011
2   01/15/2011      Weekly      156     2/5/2011
2   01/15/2011      Weekly      156     2/12/2011
2   01/15/2011      Weekly      156     2/19/2011
```

Comment: check out sas's date functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only weird fudge for this solution is for bi-weekly I've had to include a mod function to vary between increments of 3 and 4 days within a week, taking the last payment date as the base on which to increment.

I've looped from 0 to TERM-1 meaning you'll get the correct number of payment dates using the SAS function intnx to increase the dates by loop variable i.  I've used 's' for the alignment to make sure all payments align to the first payment variable.

```
data example;
format first_pmt_date SCHEDULED_PMT_DATE mmddyys10.0;
format schedule $25.;
id=1;
first_pmt_date="28JAN2011"d;
SCHEDULED_PMT_DATE=FIRST_PMT_DATE-3;
schedule='Bi-Weekly';
term=52;

do i = 0 to term-1;
    SCHEDULED_PMT_DATE=intnx('day',SCHEDULED_PMT_DATE,3+mod(i,2));
    output;
end;

id=2;
first_pmt_date="15JAN2011"d;
schedule='Weekly';
term=156;

do i = 0 to term-1;
    SCHEDULED_PMT_DATE=intnx('week',FIRST_PMT_DATE,i,'s');
    output;
end;

id=3;
first_pmt_date="23JAN2011"d;
schedule='Semi-Monthly';
term=72;

do i = 0 to term-1;
    SCHEDULED_PMT_DATE=intnx('semimonth',FIRST_PMT_DATE,i,'s');
    output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful Amit.  Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem :) Any time.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-monthly is somewhat ambiguous unless you can provide an example of exactly how you want that one to behave, but otherwise your best bet is to have an integer loop counter that increments by one and using the `intnx` function to increment the start date by that many intervals.